# DE solvable for x and y

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The following ODE 
$$y=2xy'+y^2y'^3$$
Can we solve it for x without taking x in one side ? 
I mean this method : Equations solvable for x from this link http://www.solitaryroad.com/c652.html

I differentiated the equation wrt y but could not complete to get general solution :
$$1=2+2yp^3+\frac{dp}{dy}[2x+3y^2p^2]$$

However , for example , the following problem 
$$(y-xy')^2-y'^2=1$$
I solved it for y without taking y in one side : I differentiated the equation wrt x :
$$2(y-xy')(y'-y'-xy'')-2y'y''=0$$
After simplification , we get
$$y''=0 \ \ \ OR \ \ \ \ -y'+y'x^2-xy=0$$
the general solution can be gotten from $$y''=0$$
while the singular solution can be gotten from substitution in the DE by
$$y'=\frac{xy}{x^2-1}$$
So I would like to know , when do we must take x or y in one side to be able to solve ? I think if we solve for y , we may not take y in one side ...But if we solve for x we must take x in one side ? I want to be sure of my understanding ?

Answer (score 1):

The goal here is to reduce the equation to something only in terms of $y,p,dp/dy$. If you can get $x$ to one side, it will go away after differentiation.

If you solve for $x$

$$ x = \frac{y - y^2p^3}{2p} = \frac{y}{2p}-\frac{y^2p^2}{2} $$

Then differentiate

$$ \frac{1}{p} = \frac{1}{2p} - \frac{y}{2p^2}\frac{dp}{dy} - yp^2 - y^2p\frac{dp}{dy} $$

Multiplying through by $2p^2$

$$ p + (y + 2y^2p^3)\frac{dp}{dy} + 2yp^4 = 0 $$

Then factor

$$ (1 + 2yp^3)\left(p + y\frac{dp}{dy}\right) = 0 $$

The equation is now solvable for $p = f(y)$